# Regex for detect key and value

Tags: regex

I need a regex to detect the key and value in a text file,
The key will be uppercase and the value will contain at least one lower case or digit

```
E.g.: "ADDRESS""32 street 90. ETC""AGE""13""CLASS""ABC" ....
```

Regex:

```
"[A-Z]+"`"((.*\d.*)|(.*[a-z]))"`

"[A-Z]+" to match the key
"((.*\d.*)|(.*[a-z]))" to match the value
```

But the value match the first value till the file end. Any ideas ?

Note: The regex should match ADDRESS and AGE only not CLASS

Comment: Maybe `"([A-Z]+)""([^"]*)"` will be enough? Or, ok, a more precise `"([A-Z]+)""([^"]*[a-z0-9][^"]*)"`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ix5kUn/2). Where are you using the regex? How?

Comment: Thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew this one ""([A-Z]+)""([^"]*[a-z0-9][^"]*)"" worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
"([A-Z]+)""([^"]*[a-z0-9][^"]*)"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ix5kUn/2)

**Details**

- `"` - a double quote
- `([A-Z]+)` - Group 1: one or more uppercase letters
- `""` - two `"` chars
- `([^"]*[a-z0-9][^"]*)` - Group 2:

  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
  - `[a-z0-9]` - a lowercase letter or digit
  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
- `"` - a double quote

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex-

```regex
"([A-Z]+)""([\w \.]+)"
```

This assumes the key can only contain uppercase letters (`[A-Z]`) and the value can only contain word characters (`\w`), spaces ( ), and a literal dot `\.`.

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldTlJV/2)

Use it to construct a dictionary using-

```py
>>> {k:v for k, v in re.findall(r'"(\w+)""([\w \.]+)"', '"ADDRESS""32 street 90. ETC""AGE""13"')}
{'ADDRESS': '32 street 90. ETC', 'AGE': '13'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chase, the point if the value contains only upper case , it shouldn't be match

Comment: oh I see, sure the key can be changed to `[A-Z]` then

Answer (score 0):

```
"([A-Z]*?)""(.*?([0-9]|[a-z]{1}?).*?)"
```

should work like a charm